# Which selector to write in rvest package in R?

Tags: r, css-selectors, rvest

I am trying to extract informations from source code of a specific website

In the source code there are lines:

```
# [[4]]
# <script type="text/javascript">
#   <![CDATA[
#     <!-- // <![CDATA[
#       var wp_dot_addparams = {
#         "cid": "148938",
#         "ctype": "article",
#         "ctags": "dziejesiewkulturze,piraci z karaibów,Charlie Hebdo,Scorpions",
#         "cauthor": "",
#         "csource": "film.wp.pl",
#         "cpageno": 1,
#         "cpagemax": 1,
#         "cdate": "2015-02-18"
#       };
#       // ]]]]><![CDATA[> -->
#                          ]]>
#   </script>
```

From which I'd like to extract:

```
"ctags": "dziejesiewkulturze,piraci z karaibów,Charlie Hebdo,Scorpions",
```

Does anyone know how I should specify the selector in `html_nodes` function in `rvest` package in R?

```
html("http://film.wp.pl/id,148938,title,dziejesiewkulturze-Codzienna-dawka-informacji-kulturalnych-180215-WIDEO,wiadomosc.html") %>%
  html_nodes("script")
```

Comment: You would need to retrieve the text using `html_text()` and either extract that specific line, or parse the script to obtain the portion you need. Using a selector the farthest you can go is to select this specific `script` element.

Comment: Try using gsub to replace everything outside the curly brackets and parse the resulting text as JSON

Comment: @RobertKingston I don't think it's easy to do (if even possible) and does not answer the question about a specific selector but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Extract the JSON object from the element's text (tidy the selector up while you're at it)
2. Parse it as a list using jsonlite's fromJSON() function.
3. You can access it directly using "$ctags"

   ```
   library(jsonlite)

   json <- html("http://film.wp.pl/id,148938,title,dziejesiewkulturze-Codzienna-dawka-informacji-kulturalnych-180215-WIDEO,wiadomosc.html") %>%
     html_nodes("script:contains('var wp_dot_addparams')") %>%
     gsub(x=., pattern=".*var wp_dot_addparams = (\\{.*\\});.*",replacement="\\1") %>%
     fromJSON()

   json$ctags

   [1] "dziejesiewkulturze,piraci z karaibów,Charlie Hebdo,Scorpions"
   ```

Comment: Whoah. Is `"script:contains('var wp_dot_addparams')"` this construction a java-script construction? How could one know how to specify such statement? Thanks for help - I don't remember this queastion anymore, but the answer is very educative.

Comment: Nah not quite - don't think rvest executes JS. I'm not sure where I found it but I use it a lot in jQuery. There may be more selectors you can use in rvest which are documented on the jQuery site, but I doubt they all work. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Good point @MichaelChirico - just edited it based on that. I must be running an old version.